# XAgent in Notes client

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've created an XAgent to export Notes data to Excel along the lines of the following:

http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/developer2010_xpagexlsexport.html

http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/How_to_export_to_Excel_or_other_formats

The agent works fine the first time I run it in the Notes client.  However, the second time I trigger the XAgent, I get the Location chooser letting me determine where to save the file, but nothing is ever downloaded.  Worst of all, my Notes client locks up.  I need to completely reboot my PC to get the XAgent to work again.  I'm using Notes 8.5.3

When I run the agent within IE, it works fine every time.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior when exporting data via an XAgent running in XPiNC?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to use file emitting XAgents in XPiNC. You do have access to the file system after all. So it is easier to directly write to a file and then just display the link. If you follow my [XAgent advise](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SLCVR) all your worker code would be in a class which you pass the Stream object, so you only have slightly different wrapper code around it.

So you would (pseudo-code)

```
 OutputStream out;
 if(runningInXPiNC()) {
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(determineLocalFileName()));
 } else {
   out = getOutputStreamFromContextandResponseObject();
 }
 renderThatExelFile(out);
```

The rendered property of the page would be `true` for XPiNC, so you can display "Open the file" URL that points to `"file://"+determineLocalFileName()`

Comment: I appreciate your advice.  I'm probably going to go the route of having the user request a download, then have a schedule agent process the requests and send the download via e-mail.  Sucks, but it should work without any flaky XPiNC weirdness.

Comment: Michael you don't need an scheduled agent. Just use the stream as parameter. Sample updated above